# How do I start a command from terminal so that terminal is not the parent?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Let's take example of a command "example-command".

1. I open terminal
2. I write `example-command` in terminal, and `example-command` executes.
3. Now if I close terminal, `example-command` gets killed too.
4. I now try with "`example-command &`", but the same behaviour.

How do I execute a command so that when I close the terminal, the command doesn't get terminated?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two ways, identical in result.

1. Use `nohup` when you start your program.  E.g., `nohup example-command`.  You can background and work with it normally; it will simply continue running after you've quit.
2. Alternatively, [as @alamar noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853763/292408), if you use bash as your shell, you can us the `disown` command.  Unfortunately, as far as I know, `disown` is bash-specific; if you use another shell, such `tcsh`, you may be restricted to the `nohup` form above.

Comment: zsh does also support disown.

Comment: Oh, and now I remember, I've used `nohup` in past!

Comment: From the bash man page, it looks like the "-h" option is required to ignore SIGHUP -- "disown -h".

Comment: Both options solve the killing problem, but the parent process still is the shell. On the other hand, `setsid` starts the command in a new session. Try running `ps -o cmd= $(ps -o ppid= $(pidof example-command))` to get the parent process name.

Answer (score 11):

Please search for similar questions first.

Besides the ways listed above, you can do:

```
setsid command_name
```

For example:

```
setsid xclock
```

Thanks

Comment: >> Please search for similar questions first.

*I did. Sir.*

Answer (score 7):

In Zsh (not bash) you can:

```
example-command &; disown {pid}
```

or just

```
example-command &; disown
```

Comment: The semicolon after the ampersand is a syntax error.  In bash the PID is optional, and the "-h" is needed.  So this should be: "example-command & disown -h" but this doesn't redirect stdin/stdout/stderr.

Comment: `ls &; disown` works just fine for me in zsh.

If bash doesn't support either of those (; after & or disown without parameters), then: don't tell me you didn't know that it sucks.

Comment: I agree @NVRAM. I updated the answer to say it works in Zsh but not bash.

Answer (score 5):

You could also consider using the [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) command.

Comment: or its modern alternative, `tmux`.

Answer (score 1):

nohup example-command

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ['at' or 'batch' commands](http://man.he.net/?topic=at&section=all) and give it the current time.

Comment: I like this one, but rarely use it.  And to simplify just use "at now" (no need to figure out the date/time).

Answer (score 1):

disown is a bash builtin. You could create a wrapper shellscript for your command such as

```
#!/bin/bash
$1 &
P=`which $1`
disown `pidof ${P}`
```

Not the most robust script (by any means) but may help get you going. For example:

```
$./launch_script.sh myProgram
```

You can also do this in the source of the program if you are editing it.

Comment: Your example doesn't handle arguments (use "$@").  You can use "$!" for the PID of last backgrounded job.  But the PID is not needed.  And you should ignore SIGHUP so use either "nohup" or "disown -h".

Comment: Thanks NVRAM, been a while since I did any shell scripting :)

Answer (score -2):

Run: example-command

Press: Control-Z

Run: bg

Comment: That's the same as running `example-command &`, and that did not work. `example-command` is still run as a child process.

Comment: I suggest you use screen then.
screen vi
Control+a d
[will dettach]
screen -r
[will reattach]
You can close your terminal and come back days later and do the screen -r with that user.
You can have multiple screen'd sessions.